# K&R exercise 2-5

Tags: c

"Write the function any(s1,s2), which returns the first location in the string s1 where any character from the string s2 occurs, or -1 if s1 contains no characters from s2.  (The standard library function strpbrk does the same job but returns a pointer to the location."

I'm wondering if it would be a bad habit to put a return statement within a loop instead of using "char_match = YES" as I'm doing here:

```
#define YES 1
#define NO 0
int char_seek(char string[], char string2[])
{
    int i, j;
    int char_match = NO;

    for (i = j = 0; string[i] != '\0' && char_match == NO; ++i){
        while (string2[j] != '\0' && string[i] != string2[j])
            ++j;
        if (string2[j] == '\0')
            j = 0;
        else if (string[i] == string2[j])
            char_match = YES;
    }
    if (char_match == NO)
        return -1;
    else
        return i-1;
}
```

What about return i-1? Is that bad? Should I find a different way to do this?

Comment: For readability, it would be good for you to use enclosures `{...}` around the section of code meant to be part of the `while(..)` statement.

Comment: For fun, a simplified version: `ssize_t any(const char *s1, const char *s2) { const char *p1 = s1; for (;;) { const char *p2 = s2;     do { if (*p1 == *p2) { return *p1 ? (p1 - s1) : -1; } } while (*p2++ != '\0'); p1++; } }`.  BTW: not a bad habit for multiple returns, but multiple returns should be avoided if convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Having multiple return statements is fine.
2. As a potential return statement: `return i-1;` is fine.

So you could certainly rewrite that code as:

```
int char_seek(char string[], char string2[])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = j = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        while (string2[j] != '\0' && string[i] != string2[j])
            ++j;
        if (string2[j] == '\0')
            j = 0;
        else if (string[i] == string2[j])
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Or, as I would probably write something like this:

```
int char_seek(const char *string, const char *string2) {
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; string2[j] != '\0'; ++j)
            if (string[i] == string[j])
                return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Which I think is far more readable.

As a general rule, when you're implementing a search function, I think that having a `return` statement inside the loop should be the **preferred** notation.

Also, while I know that this is a learning exercise, it's worth noting that there is a very similar function in string.h named [`strpbrk()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) that would do almost all of the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason having multiple `return` statements might be bad is if you need to do any sort of clean up before exiting the function. For example, if you allocate memory for several pointers in your particular function, then you will need to ensure that you deallocate all of them before those statements. In your particular case, having a `return` inside the loop is perfectly fine as you will not run afoul of any memory management.

Answer (score 0):

There are no valid anwsers as to whether its better using multiple returns or not, however keep in mind that - if you take the multiple returns path - you have to think about resource deallocation (FILE handle, malloc, etc) since you don't have any facilities in C like you have in other language (C++, Java, etc).

Here's your code using multiple return, and where I return `i` instead of `i - 1` (which is normal because `++i` was executed just before the end of loop^).

```
int char_seek(char string[], char string2[])
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        while (string2[j] != '\0' && string[i] != string2[j]) {
            ++j;
        }
        if (string2[j] == '\0') {
            j = 0;
        } else if (string[i] == string2[j]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

While it's not wrong to use multiple return, you should always use {} to delimits blocks (like your "else if"). And you should really avoid multiple variable initialisation like `i = j = 0`.

Comment: ***K&R exercise 2-5***, and tag==C should narrow your answer text by a few lines I think.

Comment: What do you mean by using braces to delimit blocks like my else if statement? I have no braces in my else if block.

Comment: See my post, and how I reformatted the else if blocks as well as the while loop.